# SSD on USB 3.0 doesn't always mount

Tags: 11.10, mount, mouse, automount, ssd

The SSD I use is apparently slightly damaged. At the moment it shows this popular Corsair Series 3 problem. Symptoms: the disk is working for some minutes and then just suddenly stops. Two months ago it worked like a charm. This was my boot device in these days.

So now I still need to copy some data out of the device which leads me to my question.
Usually the SSD is working again for some minutes, when i unplug and replug its power. It gets detected by the system again and I can continue my backup.
The problem on Ubuntu is, that it is not recognized again after two or three replugs. I have to reboot to bring it back.
To specify this situation: when I unplug and replug my USB mouse before I reboot it is not recognized as well. So something seems to be wrong with the system also.
my question: how do I fix this rebooting issue?

I will post all the logs you need to analyse.
The problem doesn't depend on the interface. I tried USB3.0, 2.0 and SATA already.
my system:

```
Ubuntu 11.10,
Gigabyte G41MT-S2P,
Intel E6750
Corsair Force Series 2 - F120,
Digitus USB 3.0 Adapter,
USB 3.0 interface card
```

Answer (score 0):

A piece of bad Hardware can cause other issues to happen with the OS and applications. If you know the SSD is bad, STOP using it.

If it has critical data stored on it and needs recovering, don't risk damage to your system. Have it professionally extruded.

"The problem doesnt depend on the interface. I tried USB3.0, 2.0 and SATA already".

That is a great clue to not continue. However, if you must I would recommend testdisk and photorec. Recovery applications.

Get them [here](http://www.cgsecurity.org/)